# Is this PHP script correct?

Tags: php, actionscript-3

I have an as3 script that loads a urlrequest of a PHP script with a query string and I'm not sure if it works correctly.

**AS3:**

```
userLoad=new URLLoader;
userReq=new URLRequest("http://users/redirect.php?goto=u"+meFB+"/char.xml");
userLoad.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,userLoaded);`
```

**PHP:**

```
$goto=$_REQUEST['goto'];
return readfile($goto);`
```

I recently added a directory in the path and it doesn't seem to work anymore...

since i only need 94 more points to answer my own question i'll leave the answer here: didn't tried it but i really think strings passed thru query to php have to avoid slashes spaces and others and use char encoding instead. if anyone knows that for sure please leave an answer. i just avoided the slashes and works like a charm. also is request method the security breach you guys were talking about? i'm not verry good with php so i don't know, but i could change it to get if that's better. thanks for your answers and comments btw.

Comment: FYI, what you are making is absolutely terrifying from a security stand point.  Not only can someone use this to get whatever they want from your server, but depending on configuration, can use you as a proxy.

Comment: agree about the security, but why do you need the u in ?goto=u"+...+" I think t won't work, ass soon you change the path, or am I wrong?

Comment: it completes a string - directory's name where "char.xml" can be found

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here?  The red flags we're seeing here suggest there might be a better way to do what you *really* want to accomplish.

Comment: have you tried, to debug your php script, without using flash, instead by using real url's through the browser?

Answer (score 2):

There are other ways to do it, but this is easy to understand and isn't a security hole. (And when we say security hole, your current code would let anyone have complete access to your system with minimal effort.)

The trick here is hard coding in the paths.

```
<?php
switch($_GET['goto']){
    case 'char':
    readfile('char.xml');
    break;

    case 'uchar1':
    readfile('directory/uchar.xml');
    break;

// repeat for all files
}
?>
```

Comment: true! and you are able to change the filestructure later, without touching the actionscript.

Comment: the security hole is the request method i'm currently using?

Comment: should i change request method to post? please answer

Comment: i can't use this aproach since all files and the directory are dynamically created and modified... the question was if slashes aren't wellcomed in the query strings for the php code so that i should avoid them... a lot to do if so...